# Force the numbering of a specific equation when mathtools showonlyrefs is true

Tags: cross-referencing, mathtools, subequations

In order to avoid wasting time in adding/removing `*`s to number or not equations, I use `\mathtools{showonlyrefs=true}` in the preamble.
Nevertheless, sometimes I'd like to number unreferenced equations. For instance, if just one of two subequations is referenced I want both to be numbered.
So the question is: how can I force the numbering of an unreferenced equation (or subequation) if `\mathtools{showonlyrefs=true}` is used in the preamble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mathtools` provides `\noeqref` for this purpose. To show the number of an equation with label `eq:abc`, add `\noeqref{eq:abc}`. The command is similar to `\nocite` for citations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\begin{document}
Reference to \eqref{1}.
\noeqref{3}
\begin{gather}
a=b \label{1} \\
a=c \label{2} \\
a=d \label{3} \\
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```